# Android check on installations source package name

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

To check the installation source in my app, i check if the installation source package name = com.android.vending thats how i can tell if the app. installed from google play or not.

My question is, what is HUAWEI App-Gallery store package name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking what the package name for Huawei AppGallery is, then it's `com.huawei.appmarket`. ([Reference](https://huawei-appgallery.en.uptodown.com/android))

On the other hand, if you're asking what the package name will be when the app is downloaded from Huawei AppGallery, then I was unable to find any hard reference that points to the fact that apps downloaded from Huawei AppGallery will have any package name (like `com.amazon.venezia` for Amazon store or `com.android.vending` for Google playstore).

<s>I suppose your best bet would be to check if the package name contains `"com.huawei"`. (**Do note that I can't provide any assurety that this would work**)</s>

**Update** - OP has confirmed with HUAWEI technical team that the installation source package name will be `"com.huawei.appmarket"`.

Comment: I've created a case for HUAWEI technical team and they confirmed that If the app is installed through Huawei AppGallery, then the installation source package name will be  "com.huawei.appmarket".

Comment: Cool, I've edited the answer. Mark the answer if it answered you question. Cheers.